# .htaccess rewrite rule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been looking few different tutorials about it like

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

and I thought it would be easy to do my own rewrite rule but I don't know why it's not working.

this is what I have in my htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp2/
RewriteRule ^lol portafolio  [NC,L]    # Change feed URL
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and when I write wwww.domain.com/wp2/lol it's not redirecting me to wwww.domain.com/wp2/portafolio which this code:

```
RewriteRule ^lol portafolio  [NC,L]    # Change feed URL
```

should do.. I guess it's not correct. Why it's not doing the rewriting correctly? I need to rewrite a bunch of URLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. it will help you

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```